# How to get all versions of an artifact on Nexus via API or Maven?

Tags: maven, nexus3

I have some pom artifacts uploaded to Nexus and I want to get through a curl or maven command or through an mvn command all the versions that are uploaded of that artifact. How would it be possible?

Comment: Have you taken a look into the api documentation of Nexus3 ? Its available directly from Nexus itself...

Comment: Nexus has a web interface where you can see this manually.

Comment: In the end he decided to curl the metadata followed by a grep to get only the versions.

curl ${URL_NEXUS}/maven-metadata.xml | grep -Po '(?<=<version>)([0-9\.]+(-SNAPSHOT)?)'| sort --version-sort -r